# Delete button in TableView does not dissapear

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I've got a little problem (it's really not that big of a deal but it annoys me), because after I delete a record from my table, I also want my *delete button* to disapear, right now it works like this:

**BEFORE** clicking the **DELETE** button:

[image]

**AFTER** clicking first record's **DELETE** button:

[image]

Also, this is the function that I'm using to handle this event:

```
private class ButtonCell extends TableCell<Record, Boolean> {
    final Button cellButton = new Button("Delete");

    ButtonCell(){

        cellButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent t){

                Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
                alert.setTitle("Confirmation Dialog");
                alert.setHeaderText("Delete the entire row?");

                Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
                if (result.get() == ButtonType.OK){
                    Animal currentAnimal = (Animal) ButtonCell.this.getTableView().getItems().get(ButtonCell.this.getIndex());
                    data.remove(currentAnimal);
                    cellButton.setVisible(false);
                }
            }
        });

    }
    //Display button if the row is not empty
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Boolean t, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(t, empty);
        if(!empty){
            setGraphic(cellButton);

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: there should be a answer?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22574239/how-to-delete-a-javafx-tableview-row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Override
protected void updateItem(Boolean t, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(t, empty);
    if(empty){
        setGraphic(null);
    } else {
        setGraphic(cellButton);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly :)